# Swift-C interop: warning: dylib was built for newer macOS version (12.0) than being linked (11.0)

Tags: c, swift, llvm

I'm loosely following [enter link description here](http://marcusrossel.com/2020-06-02/kaleidoscope-3) guide to use LLVM in swift, and I was able to successfully import `CLLVM` into a swift project. However I get the following warning when I build a project using `CLLVM`:

```
ld: warning: dylib (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/lib/libLLVM-13.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (12.0) than being linked (11.0)
```

I can't seem to find any information about this specific problem, and I want to make sure there aren't any problems with LLVM that could mess me up later.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install an older version of `llvm`.

According to the [llvm brew page](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/llvm) `brew install llvm` installs llvm 13. Try installing an older version and see if your warning goes away. You can try:

`brew install llvm@12`

or

`brew install llvm@11`